# Is there a matlab function(s) I can use to create a realistic diagram of the I.S.S?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

As part of a project I am undertaking at the moment, I have to solve the two-body problem of the international space station orbiting the Earth. I have managed to approximate this so far by using the sphere/surf function, however, I was wondering if there was any way I could create a more realistic figure representing the ISS? Unfortunately,this project has to be done solely through MATLAB so I cannot use any other tools which may provide better visualisation

Comment: Please clarify: Are you trying to first print a 3D globe and then have a 3D model of the ISS visible over its orbit? In realistic sizes, it will look like a point mass if the whole globe is to appear on screen.

Comment: I have already printed a 3D globe of earth, and yes i want a 3D model visible over the orbit. Currently, I have a globe orbiting the earth but I would like to replace this with a realistic model of the ISS. Sizes do not need to be realistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASA has 3D models of many objects, including the ISS, [which can be found here](https://nasa3d.arc.nasa.gov/detail/iss-c2). This file can be converted to an STL however you want, I found [this random website](https://www.makexyz.com/convert/3ds-to-stl) which worked for me.

In Matlab, you can read in this file via

```
stl = stlread('isscombined.stl');
V = stl.Points;
F = stl.ConnectivityList
```

Then, you can plot it using

```
p = patch('vertices',V,'faces',F,'FaceColor',[.8 .8 .8]);
```

and then you can update the object with new vertex positions as the station orbits the Earth. Obviously, you can also scale the object by multiplying the vertices by some amount. If you don't want the facet edges plotted, you can also add `'EdgeAlpha', 0` to your `patch` options.

Here's a simple example which shows the ISS orbiting around a sphere

```
% Note: not to scale
ISS_radius = 2; % distance from center of Earth
RE = 1; % radius of earth
theta = 0:.05:2*pi;
x = ISS_radius*cos(theta);
y = ISS_radius*sin(theta);

stl = stlread('isscombined.stl');
r = .01; % scaling factor
V = stl.Points * r;
V = V - mean(V); % center at origin
F = stl.ConnectivityList;

figure; hold on;
plot3(x,y,zeros(numel(theta)),'--');
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(50);
surf(RE*X,RE*Y,RE*Z,'FaceColor',[0 0 .8],'EdgeAlpha',0);
p = patch('Vertices', V*r, 'Faces', F, 'FaceColor', [0 0 0], 'EdgeAlpha', 0);
axis equal;
set(gca,'View',[200 13])
grid on;
counter = 1;
while true
    p.Vertices = V + [x(counter), y(counter), 0];
    pause(0.01);
    drawnow
    counter = mod(counter + 1, numel(theta)) + 1;
    axis([-1 1 -1 1 -1 1]*ISS_radius*1.2)
end
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help! that all works, Im just still a bit confused about the orbit. Previously when I was approximating the orbit by a sphere I interpolated the sphere I implemented the following code to interpolate the path of the ISS with the image of a sphere:

`ISS=surf((x*r_ISSs)+v_ISS(1,k),(y*r_ISSs)+v_E(2,k), (z*r_ISSs)+v_E(3,k));
 set(ISS,'facecolor','texturemap','cdata',ISS_im,'edgecolor','none','FaceLighting','flat');`

where v_ISS is a containing its displacements for each given time, and ISS_im is an image of the iss. How could I modify this to include the patch

Comment: I don't understand your equation (what are the dimensions of x, y, and z and where do they come from? What is v_E? Does v_ISS designate positions or directions?), but I've added some example code which produces an orbiting ISS. See if that helps answer your question